# Getting errors when installing and running Selenium, Pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I just installed selenium and when i did a pip check selenium I am seeing the following:
qdarkstyle 2.8.1 requires helpdev, which is not installed.
spyder 4.1.4 has requirement pyqt5<5.13; python_version >= "3", but you have pyqt5 5.15.1.
spyder 4.1.4 has requirement pyqtwebengine<5.13; python_version >= "3", but you have pyqtwebengine 5.15.1.

when i try to run a basic program(Displayed below) in Pycharm im seeing exceptions:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("../Drivers/chromedriver.exe")

driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)

driver.get("http://google.com")

driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("Automation step by step")

driver.find_element_by_name("btnK").click()

time.sleep(2)

driver.close()

driver.quit()


print("Test")

--------------------
"/Applications/Python 3.8/IDLE.app/Contents/MacOS/Python" /Users/Anu/PycharmProjects/pythonProject3/Demo/test1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Anu/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../Drivers/chromedriver.exe'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Anu/PycharmProjects/pythonProject3/Demo/test1.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("../Drivers/chromedriver.exe")
  File "/Users/Anu/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/Users/Anu/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Comment: Does it work if you change `../Drivers/chromedriver.exe` to the full system path?

Comment: Have you tried using absolute path instead of relative (`"../Drivers/chromedriver.exe"`)

Comment: Could you please format your code? You'll need to use three backticks before and after the block of code.

Comment: Check or change chrome driver location this might be creating issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are passing the wrong path to the ChromeDriver, try to put the ChromeDriver in the Project directory.
Also from my understanding you are running on Windows OS, U need to add the ChromeDriver as an exe file on sys PATH variables.

https://developers.refinitiv.com/sites/default/files/How%20To%20Add%20ChromeDriver%20To%20System%20Variables_0.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Your errors maby for your Chrome driver. you can use `webdriver-manager`
for installing this module use `pip install webdriver-manager` and paste this line to your scripts

`from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())`